# Sort vector of string as dates "yyyymmdd"

Tags: c++

What's the best way to sort a vector of string that represent dates in format "yyyymmdd"

```
std::Vector<std::string> dates= {"19871010", "19991010", 19991011" ...};
```

Should I create custom sort function? or something else?

Comment: I think std::sort would do the job.

Comment: Does `1011` mean "Oct-11" or "Nov-10"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lexical order is good, so you may just use `std::sort` without custom compare functor:

```
std::sort(dates.begin(), dates.end());
```

Comment: Yes, it's correct, I think it's work because the date format is "yyyymmdd", but if the date format was "yyyyddmm" we need something different right?

Comment: Yes then you will need a custom compare.